# Retrieving selected rows in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

i'm creating a tableview which contain city names which i retrieve from a parse database. I've implemented multiple selection using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate methods. When a user is done selected cities i want to save them in the parse database, but when the user come back i want it to have the selected cities selected from the beginning.

How can i implement this? Do i need to save the indexPath in my parse database and then retrieve it and then compare it to the indexPaths in the tableView or a better solution?

## cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UserCell *cell = (UserCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
       cell.textLabel.text  = [[self.filteredCandyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[cityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    }



    if ([cellSelected containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }
    return cell;
}
```

## didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    //if you want only one cell to be selected use a local NSIndexPath property instead of array. and use the code below
    //self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    //the below code will allow multiple selection
    if ([cellSelected containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [cellSelected removeObject:indexPath];
        }
        else
        {
            [cellSelected addObject:indexPath];
        }
        [tableView reloadData];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving `NSIndexPath`s in `cellSelected`, save city names. Then once you come back to this tableview controller again, you can simply fetch selected city names and populate the `cellSelected` array

Comment: How do i compare the city names to the selected Array?

Comment: What comparison you need to make?

Comment: why dont you save indexPath.row of selected cities in NSMutableArray, then when you will call your city names again, just control it in loop and checkmark it if exist in Array.

Comment: but when i come back to the viewcontroller the selected city array will be empty?

Comment: @FrederikHagelund, Yes you have two options, either fetch them back from Parse (if you are saving them there) or fill `cellSelected` from the ViewController you're coming from (this might be a bit diffucult if you're having multiple entry points to this TableViewController)